# Wiring an event to a javascript method through xsl

Tags: javascript, xslt

I am working on a project where data is retrieved in xml and then you format it using xsl.I want to ensure that one of my textboxes only allow the users to enter alphabets.
How can I achieve the equivalent of input type="text" id="name" name="name" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event,this)"  through xsl.
I have an existing code and I have to do it without altering the already written code.So I want to do it by adding an attribute to the textbox field.

Comment: Do you know exactly how you want the resulting document (HTML + Javascript) to look like?

Comment: It can do normally. Can you please provide your code.

Comment: sorry i did not check the end result of my post. my code part was not getting displayed because of script tags

Comment: Just put the code you want as literal result in your XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: I tried something like that xsl:attribute name="onkeypress" Javascript:onlyAlphabets(e, t) xsl:attribute but it did not work

Comment: @ michael.hor257k can you please show me the way to do it with code

Comment: this my xsl <input type="text" id="txtCity" name="txtCity" style="width:200px">
              <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="/DataRecord/Record/Name"/></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="onkeypress">Javascript:onlyAlphabets(e, t)</xsl:attribute>
            </input>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a literal result element: `<input type="text" id="name" name="name" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event,this)" value="{/DataRecord/Record/Name}"/>`. In the days of HTML5 you could also consider to use the `pattern` attribute on the `input` element `<input type="text" id="name" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" value="{/DataRecord/Record/Name}"/>` instead on relying on Javascript and key event handling.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.It is a legacy code and it is client's requirement to follow the pattern of the already written code so HTML5 attributes cant be used.